# Grails Search Map

Tags: grails, groovy

I am a Java programmer trying to write some Groovy code.

I want to iterate through the map called loginAttributevalues, and for each key (e.g. username) find the cross-reference attribute value and print this:

john : display_name

However, I am having trouble getting my Java brain around the Groovy syntax.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks.

```
loginAttributeValues = [username: 'john', email: 'john@smith.com']

def mapXref = [username: 'display_name',
               firstname: 'first_name',
               lastname: 'last_name',
               email: 'email'}



for (String x : loginAttributeValues) {
    if (mapXref[x])
        println(mapXref.get(x))
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
loginAttributeValues = [username: 'john', email: 'john@smith.com']

def mapXref = [username: 'display_name',
               firstname: 'first_name',
               lastname: 'last_name',
               email: 'email']


def newMap = [:]
loginAttributeValues.each {k, v ->
     newMap << (k in mapXref.keySet() ? [(v): mapXref[k]] : [:])
}

assert newMap.'john' == 'display_name'
assert newMap.'john@smith.com' == 'email'
```

I hope you need a map like

`[john:display_name, john@smith.com:email]`

but why do you need a value `john` as a `key` and `display_name` as `value`. should not it be otherwise. In that case, you would need

```
newMap << (k in mapXref.keySet() ? [mapXref[k] : v] : [:])
```

which would assert as

```
assert newMap.display_name == 'john'
assert newMap.email == 'john@smith.com'
```

**Note:-**
If it is guaranteed that `loginAttributeValues` will have `keys` subset of the `keys` in `mapXref`, then the logic can be optimized as below

```
def newMap = loginAttributeValues.collectEntries{k, v ->
    [v, mapXref[k]]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
loginAttributeValues.each {
    if (mapXref[it])
        println(mapXref.get(it))
}
```

The Java for : each syntax is not valid in groovy. You are best of using an `each` closure.

Or, if you really want to keep the for loop syntax, then substitute `in` for `:`.